# Bug in SQL Server Management Studio Imported Tables not showing using 'Add Table' in Views

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SSMS v18.10, but it really relates to any version prior.
If you import a Table using Import flat file the Table is not visible for creation of Views
unless you restart SSMS. You can "Refresh" the Database and or Tables but this does nothing to help table availability for View creation in Design mode. You can save the half edited view and then go Design and 'Add Table' but still not see the newly added table. I find the only way to view the new table is to restart SSMS. If you are half way through some work and have 10, 20, 50 or 100 views and tables open it is grossly counterproductive to have to shut down everything and restart fresh. Does anyone know a way around this? Thankyou for your time.

Comment: In the Add Table window, under the list of tables, is a Refresh button. Clicking the Refresh button there works for me (even if I imported a Flat File in a whole other SSMS instance leaving the Add Table window open here), does it not work for you?

Comment: OMG... genius here didn't ever think to click that big refresh button... on the exact relevant screen.... and it works immediately... !@$*... Thankyou... looks like I am @AlwaysLearning too. thankyou again... I will probably delete this embarrassment ?..... later....

Comment: if you don't have a lot of user you can active auto refresh in setting window.

Comment: Instead of deleting, better to add an answer with screenshots and everything. Note: you can answer your own question.

Comment: Here is the image of the refresh button...
![Click to view image](https://GEOSPATIAL.LAND/images/so/SSMS_Views_Refresh_Tables_Button.JPG)